# Can't connect to localhost from Chrome extension

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, localhost

I am working on a Chrome extension that tracks time, and uses Google App Engine for the backend.

For testing, I'm trying to connect a local version of the extension to a local version of the App Engine app. When I try to send a POST request, I'm getting:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/report. Origin chrome-extension://mbndmimplohfkkcincjodnfpaapbbmei is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

But it works when I change the URL so that it posts to the appspot.com URL.

What is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and why is it stopping me from getting results from localhost?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe this is because you cannot make calls to a server that is not included in the permissions section of your manifest. The permissions section of manifest.json should look something like this:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://myapp.appspot.com/*",
    "http://localhost/*"
]
```

Note, I haven't tested this, but it sounds like that is where your problem is coming from.

Comment: Small correction. You can make requests even if it's not in the permissions, but unless CORS is configured to allow this on the server it will fail.

Comment: I already configured the permission for localhost but it still not work. Anyone can help?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky did you have to configure or do anything with CORS? Is adding localhost to permissions enough?

Comment: today, for this purpose, the permission field is called "host_permissions" instead of "permissions". [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/declare_permissions/#host-permissions)

Answer (score 7):

You *can* use custom ports.

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": ["http://localhost/*"]
```

**background.js** (using jQuery)

```
$.post('http://localhost:5000/some-endpoint');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this code to work:

```
var loginPayload = {};
loginPayload.username = document.getElementById('username').value;
loginPayload.password = document.getElementById('password').value;
console.log(loginPayload);

var callback = function (response) {
    console.log(response);
};
var handle_error = function (obj, error_text_status){
    console.log(error_text_status + " " + obj);
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8443/hello',
    type: 'POST',
    success: callback,
    data: JSON.stringify(loginPayload),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    error: handle_error
});
```

EDIT:
Apparently someone didn't like this, so a few things to keep in mind:

1. For extensions that have to work on https, make sure your server is serving https.
2. Contrary to posts above, chrome extensions CAN serve on ports other than port 80 / 443

Answer (score 1):

if you want a generic localhost approach

```
*://localhost:*/*
```