# Ember Inspector won't detect application using Grunt

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, yeoman, inspector

I'm currently digging into Ember.js, using Yeoman as an automation tool for project deployment. Since Grunt is already included in Yeoman, I'm using it to fire up a Grunt Server everytime I'm working on my project.

I just started my very first Ember.js project using Yeoman when I realized, that Chrome's Ember Inspector Extension isn't able to detect my application as an Ember.js app when I'm running my Grunt Server at localhost. I've already checked the "Allow access to file URLs" option within the Extension settings, still no detection.
When I work on the project without running the Grunt Server, Ember Inspector detects my application immediately.

Any solution how I can use the Inspector while running Grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Change your grunt to run on port 80.

Honestly it might be a problem localhost not being allowed with the extension, but I have a hard time believing that.  [Can't connect to localhost from Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668502/cant-connect-to-localhost-from-chrome-extension)