# Issues Connecting databse to Chrome extension

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome

I am trying to make a Chrome extension. Currently I have an AWS database running on MySQL workbench and I am trying to get it connected to the extension. My PHP file is simply just trying to connect to the database on the submit of an HTML form. I am following the videos (parts 1-4) form this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpLbADRh830

Right now I am using localhost as my server and on submit of the form, my extension says "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect." I have no clue where to go from here and this is honestly my first database experience so I apologize if this is a silly problem.

```
<?php
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $email;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost/db/tester_script.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is how I fixed the solution:

```
    <body>
    <form id="thing">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name"><br>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email"> 
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$("#thing").on("submit", function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8000/tester_script.php",
        data: {name : name, email : email},
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
        });
    return false;
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You should first check the security group of your AWS database to make sure that your IP address is not being blocked

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I did do that and it's not.

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages in the development console other than the one you describe?

Comment: No, the console stays clean. When I open the script.php file in the browser with local host, it registers so I know local host is running fine. The only error is the one that pops up when I try to submit the form in the chrome extension.  Sorry this doesn't help much. I just have no clue what is going wrong. I followed the video tutorial exactly.

Comment: Can you post any source code? It may help in determining the issue .... (Do not reveal  any connection usernames/passwords)

Comment: I made a small tester that follows the tutorial that I provided the link above except I didn't go as far as to push to the database. I am simply now just trying to send the HTML form input the the PHP script and have it echo out the variables and I still get the localhost error.

Code in edit above.

Comment: Are you sure the form's action is correct? I assume `http://localhost` shows you're index page ?

Comment: I guess I am not sure what else it should be. The tutorial did this same thing. Should it just be /db/tester_script.php? I actually just tested with this and it just spits out the PHP script content.

Comment: It looks like you have not set up you're server environment properly.

Comment: I go to the directory of my PHP script and run "php -S localhost:8000"
If I go to "localhost:8000/tester_script.php" it will print any simple echo statements that don't have variables. When I try to run it in the extension with variables it doesn't work.

Comment: Change the action url to `http://localhost:8080/db/tester_script.php`

Comment: My mistake: Should be: `http://localhost:8000/db/tester_script.php`

Comment: Remember that you need to run `php -S localhost:8000` after every reboot

Comment: Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
This is the error when I change the action. I test the script file in local host before trying it in the extension. I can get it to echo when I just run localhost:8000/db/tester_script.php. But then the chrome extension still errors

Comment: Perhaps this may help: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668502/cant-connect-to-localhost-from-chrome-extension

Comment: Jamie_D Thank you so much for constant help. I had tried the link you provided. Here was my issue:

I had to send the html form data as a JSON object rather than as variables from the form. So my PHP script only takes the form data from the JSON post object. 
Also, I added ajax post request and had to format it correctly to get the post to work. I added some example code above for anyone else that may run into this issue.