# Chrome Vue debugger for chrome-extensions?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm debugging an unpacked extension loaded from a folder. The page URL is `chrome-extension://op...` and the page uses Vue. The Vue chrome debugger extension shows "Vue JS not detected". I have enabled "Allow access to file URLs" for the extension but it still cannot detect Vue JS. Are `chrome-extension` URLS really inaccessible to Vue JS debugger? If so, how do I enable Vue debugger for extensions?

Comment: Are you talking about Vue devtools? You cannot have them running? Are you sure that you did downloaded the correct version of devtools? The first one on this page is for Vue3 (v6), then second one is for Vue2 (v5). https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/vue?hl=en

Comment: Yes, the correct version.

Comment: Never worked with Chrome extensions but if you access a `chrome-extension://op` URL, it should be bundled for production right? Hence do not have any kind of info available publicly. I guess that you should have it running locally on your machine and then, you could access it through usual `localhost`.

Comment: I don't think I can run it from localhost, there are two html pages `popup.html` and `index.html` and if I run it from localhost they won't communicate.

Comment: @kissu Well I decided not to use the debugger but the answer you linked seems as it is going to work. I would award the bounty if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `manifest.json` looking like this

```json
"permissions": [
    "http://myapp.appspot.com/*",
    "http://localhost/*"
]
```

As shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7675088/8816585