# Access to localhost has been blocked by CORS policy [Chrome extension]

Tags: google-chrome, networking, google-chrome-extension

Please note that all similar questions I could find on SO are ones trying to access localhost from a **website**, and I'm trying to access from an **extension.**

The difference? A website you just need to update to https, but I cannot update my extension to https. The origin is `chrome-extension://` not even `http://`

The error is as follows:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1784/myrestapi' from origin **'chrome-extension://asjdkhjhgaqnmpasorhwkq'** has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.

You see, that renders all suggestions to make the origin https invalid.

I've tried disabling the `block-insecure-private-network-requests` flag and enabling `allow-insecure-localhost` flag, but unfortunately they're of no use. It seems a ridiculous idea having to make the localhost https.

The host permission does include all urls for the extension, and this is only happening on some machines, and it runs perfectly on the other computers, all with the latest chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to localhost from Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668502/cant-connect-to-localhost-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: No, and as I have already stated in my question, I do have the proper host permission. Thus the answer of the question you've linked is what I've already done.

Comment: you may not like the answer, but the question is still a duplicate.

Comment: OK, consider this as a follow-up question then? Coz the answer in that question doesn't work, and I've clear stated so (that I do have host permission) in my question so that makes my question have a different precondition than the other one

Comment: Maybe you didn't reload the extension after editing? Try specifying [CSP in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/content_security_policy/). See if `chrome://policy` page has localhost in ExtensionSettings' runtime_blocked_hosts.